# Does C# have a method for parsing an int, meanwhile keeping track of the number of characters parsed?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, parsing

I have a program whose input is like

```
~1^(2~&3) 0x3FFE 0x2FCE 0xFCC1
```

and right now I'm constructing the algorithm that parses the equation

```
~1^(2~&3)
```

and hopefully I'll be able to do it without any repeated passes through sections of the equation. **Does C#, in it standard libraries, have a way of parsing an `int` an keeping track of the number of characters parsed?** So that, for example, if I'm at the point

```
~1207300&11
 ^
```

in an equation then I want to be able to grab `1207300` and know that I parsed 7 characters so that I can move 7 indixes forward to

```
~1207300&11
        ^
```

Or will I have to hand-roll such a function?

Comment: First split it based on a certain character or regular expresion -- afterwards parse everything individually.

Comment: This is a standard dijkstra algorithm with 2 stacks. One for operators, one for numbers.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I not asking how to construct the algotithm in total. I'm asking about how to implement a specific subroutine of how I've decided to write the algorithm.

Comment: Ok I got. Just iterate over chars. Use temp string. When you get digit append to temp string. When you get non digit push string to stack and assign it empty string. You can instead remember position of first digit and then use substring as well.

Comment: ~1207300&11 is not a number and thus it cannot be parsed as a number (`int` or any other type). It has to be treated as what it is (= a string or a set of characters or similar), during the corresponding analysis (= substrings/characters of that string) you might find numbers and store them in a variable with the corresponding type (via conversion from string to that type). Creating such an analysing/converting algorithm is quite straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does C#, in it standard libraries, have a way of parsing an int an keeping track of the number of characters parsed?

No, unfortunately not. All the parsing routines expect the input to be a number and nothing else. (Whitespace is also allowed and ignored.)

Find out how many chars are in the number by running a simple loop. Then, `Substring` the number out and pass it to `int.Parse`.

Comment: Ehhh .... I'm trying to be as efficient as possible. I don't want to have to create new strings in my procedure. I'm using the starting string and if I ever need a substring I pass a reference to the starting string along with the bounds of the substring.

Comment: Then you need to do the int parsing yourself. Does that answer the question?

Comment: "*I'm trying to be as efficient as possible. I don't want to have to create new strings in my procedure.*" - Are you fixing a bottleneck or is this premature optimization rearing it's ugly head @FailedComputerScience101